# How to focus deep nested input from root component in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, focus

I have component in component in component. So in the root component i want to focus input in the deepest child when i am clicking somewhere in .grandparent-container.

As you can see in the example i could have multiple components on the page. So i need to focus only child input of the clicked component.  Here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o26vaj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

I tried to create a `[focus]` directive, but it works only if i have one grandparent on the page, because directive can't to figure out what exactly input it should focus.

Select element by id is not the case also.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a simple focus messaging service using an Observable Subject. Clicked controller tells the service it has been clicked. Child controller subscribes and sets focus. Good use case for a component-scoped provider.

Here's a fork of your example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1nbbk8

Comment: Just replaced the link with a slightly better version.

Comment: Great. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Excellent solution, I've implemented it on my app. Thanks